# Vignette creation on package build fails with the error "Failed to locate the ‘weave’ output file"

Tags: r, knitr

I've written an R package, which lives [here](https://github.com/Ironholds/reconstructr) and contains [a vignette](https://github.com/Ironholds/reconstructr/blob/master/vignettes/session%20reconstruction.Rmd) intended to step users through the rationale behind the package and how to best use it.

Unfortunately, on an attempt to build a source or binary package, the vignette construction fails with the following error:

```
* creating vignettes ... ERROR
Error: processing vignette 'session reconstruction.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
Failed to locate the ‘weave’ output file (by engine ‘knitr::rmarkdown’) for vignette with name ‘session reconstruction’. The following files exist in directory ‘.’: ‘session reconstruction.Rmd’, ‘session_clusters.png’, ‘session_reconstruction.html’
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Version information on the machine I'm building on:

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "linux-gnu"

$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "1.2"

$year
[1] "2014"

$month
[1] "10"

$day
[1] "31"

$`svn rev`
[1] "66913"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)"

$nickname
[1] "Pumpkin Helmet"
```

I've googled around and there doesn't seem to be a "proper" diagnosis: people have reported encountering similar errors, normally fixed with an upgrade to R 3.1.0 (which I'm using. Well, past using). Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but generally you should avoid spaces in filenames.

Comment: Okay, if anyone else figures out the root problem, please feel free to post the real answer :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I did not fully investigate the problem, but it seems that removing the spaces in the filename solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem so I came to this site. I had constructed a vignette "Intro to XXX.Rmd", which failed. I changed the file to "Intro_to_XXX.Rmd" and R CMD check (CMD/Shift E in RStudio) worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error from a vignette in a file named "time2nextNuclearWeaponState.Rmd" in my local development version of "github.com/sbgraves237/Ecfun".  The problem occurred with:

output: bookdown::gitbook

When I changed to "output: html_document", the problem disappeared.  This was using the current version of everything (R, RStudio, all packages) on 2019-11-14 under macOS 10.15.1.  If you download this file and the companion "nuc-references.bib" and change "output" to "bookdown::gitbook", I believe you will likely replicate the problem.

Or if you have this problem with "output: bookdown::gitbook" you should be able to get past it using "output: html_document".  If you still need "output: bookdown::gitbook", I hope these comments will help you isolate and fix the problem.